# Shell script and CRON problems

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I've written a backup script for our local dev server (running Ubuntu server edition 9.10), just a simple script to tar & gzip the local root and stick it in a backup folder. 
It works fine when I run :

```
$ bash backups.sh
```

but it wont work when I run it through crontab.

```
59 23 *  *  *  bash /home/vnc/backups/backup.sh >> /home/vnc/backups/backup.log 2> $1
```

I get the error message

```
/bin/sh: cannot create : nonexistent
```

The script makes the tar.gz in the folder it is running from (/home/user1), but then tries to copy it to a mounted share (/home/backups, which is really 192.168.0.6/backups) from a network drive, via using fstab.
The mounted share has permissions 777 but the owner and group are different to those running the script.
I'm using bash to run the script instead of sh to get around another issue I've had in the past with "bad substitution" errors

The first 2 lines of the file are

```
! /bin/bash

cd /home/vnc/backups
```

I'm probably not supplying enough information to fully answer this post yet but I can post more information as necessary, but I don't really know where to look next.

Comment: I'd guess that the difference is an environment. Try to dump the environment (via `set` or via `declare`) to some temporary file and compare. Most likely it has something to do with working directory or something like that.

Comment: `env` is more suitable for printing environment information, sorry for misleading you.

Comment: I'm not sure what I need to compare? Running `env` shows I'm using `/bin/bash/`, I'm not trying to use `/bin/sh/` anywhere so I can't understand why the error is related to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clue is in the error message:

```
/bin/sh: cannot create : nonexistent
```

Notice that it says "sh". The Bourne shell doesn't support some features that are specific to Bash. If you're using Bash features, then you need to tell Bash to run the script.

Make the first line of your file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or in your crontab entry do this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash scriptname
```

Without seeing your crontab entry and your script it's hard to be any more specific.

Comment: Already got both of those lines in! I'll update the original post

Comment: Ah wait a sec, I've written "bash" instead of "/bin/bash" in crontab, I'll update to the absolute path and see how that works... ok, that made no difference either

Comment: @Comcar: Ah, I now see where your problem is. There's no contents for `$1` that you're sending your standard output to in the crontab entry. You need to specify a filename. It makes no sense to use `$1`. It's meaningless in that context. Also, in your edit, you have the shebang as "! /bin/bash". It needs to be `#! /bin/bash`.

Comment: @Comcar: If you mean for stderr to go to the same place as stdout, then it needs to be `2>&1` instead of "2> $1".

Comment: Sorry yes I do have the `#!`, just didn't copy the full line. And I can't believe it's just a typo after all that. The crontab wasn't running because of the $/& error. What a fool I've been. Thanks Dennis!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the first thing you should do in your `backups.sh` is insert a `cd /home/user1`. `crond` may execute your script from a different directory than you think it does, and forcing it to use the same directory regardless of how it is executed could be a good first start.

Another potentially useful debugging step is to add `id > /tmp/id.$$` or something like that, so you can see exactly which user account and groups are being used to run your script.

Comment: I've already got the cd in the top of the file, I added id >> this.log to the script as the first line but it doesn't even get there far.

Where you suggesting I add it to the crontab file?

Answer (score 1):

In crontab, just change 2>$1 to 2>&1. I've just done one myself. Thank you  Dennis Williamson.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as to why that error is coming

Comment: His original code has 2>$1 and the explanation was answered by Dennis Williamson.