# Git server set up issue

Tags: git, ubuntu

I was setting up my gitserver on a lucid VPS following this tutorial 
http://kris.me.uk/2010/09/30/git-repository-server-gitolite.html

It worked up until this line:

```
    src/gl-system-install ~/bin ~/share/gitolite/conf ~/share/gitolite/hooks
```

I got this in the output:

```
    bash: src/gl-system-install: No such file or directory
```

This is my first time setting up a git server so I am a bit lost, I googled the problem but nothing I could find makes sense. I appreciate the help guys!

Comment: Is there a `src` directory in your current directory containing the `gl-system-install` command?  If not, you're probably running the command in the wrong place.  If there *is*, what does the first line of the script look like?

Comment: When following tutorials, you need to ensure versions that you install match the tutorial, or you will have issues like this.

That tutorial is from 2010 and some changes back.  Likely you have installed a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

`gl-system-install` is a Gitolite command, and [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) has moved to [V3 (or 'g3')](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html).
In V3, `gl-system-install` doesn't exist, is now called gitolite (and `gitolite-shell`)

```
gitolite/install -to $HOME/bin
gitolite setup -pk YourName.pub
```

See the **[Gitolite installation page](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html)** for an updated setup procedure.

> "Installation" consists of the following options:
>
> 1. Keep the sources anywhere and use the full path to run the `gitolite` command.
> 2. Keep the sources anywhere and symlink just the `gitolite` program to some directory on your `$PATH`.
> 3. Copy the sources somewhere and use that path to run the `gitolite` command.
>
> Option 2 is the best for general use.

```
# option 2
gitolite/install -ln
# defaults to $HOME/bin (which is assumed to exist)
#   ** or **
# or use a specific directory (please supply full path):
gitolite/install -ln /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Hi.

i am trying to install gitolite from the ReadMe file you linked and i keep getting this error:


root@linxuServer:/# gitolite/install -to $HOME/bin
-bash: gitolite/install: No such file or directory

the command you posted simply doesnt work

Comment: @jonney it does, if you are in the parent directory of gitolite/install. Note that I never do installation as root. See a more complete example in https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh: You will have access to gitolite/install after cloning the gitolite repo.

Comment: Hi. i managed to get it to work by deleteing the gitollite folder and starting again doing a git clone.

Comment: @jonney Excellent. That is why I wrote this `install_or_update_gitolite.sh` script: it does everything automatically.

Comment: Do u have that .sh script handy that i can use?

Comment: @jonney you need to adapt it (because I use my own environment variable 'H' and a system of template variables), but sure: I mentioned it in my previous comment: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh (for instance, you don't need `xxgit=1 `: just `git` is enough. And `gen_sed` is my own wrapper for the `sed` command: use `sed` directly).

Comment: Thanks. looks good. what programming language is that?  offtopic but i want to create some kind of script for syncing and backing up stuff on my network.

setting up git on ubutnu server is no easy task though :(

Comment: @jonney simple bash script. Note git and backup don't go well together: http://serverfault.com/questions/274240/backup-solution-for-10tb-using-ubuntu (you cazn try gibak though, not tested: http://blog.philippklaus.de/2010/02/git-for-synchronization-and-backup/)

Comment: im guessing bash scripts can be run periodically?

Comment: @jonney Yes. Bash is included with Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting. And you can use cron to run it periodically: http://askubuntu.com/questions/117978/script-doesnt-run-via-crontab-but-works-fine-standalone , http://stackoverflow.com/a/5065368/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812425/bash-script-not-executing-in-cron-correctly